# How to check JSON data in Python

Tags: json

Data sample:

```
import pandas as pd

patients_df = pd.read_json('C:/MyWorks/Python/Anal/data_sample.json', orient="records", lines=True)

patients_df.head()

//in python



//my json data sample

  "data1": {
    "id": "myid",
    "seatbid": [
      {
        "bid": [
          {
            "id": "myid",
            "impid": "1",
            "price": 0.46328014,
            "adm": "adminfo",
            "adomain": [
              "domain.com"
            ],
            "iurl": "url.com",
            "cid": "111",
            "crid": "1111",
            "cat": [
              "CAT-0101"
            ],
            "w": 00,
            "h": 00
          }
        ],
        "seat": "27"
      }
    ],
    "cur": "USD"
  },
```

What I want to do is to check if there is a **"cat"** value in my very large JSON data.
The **"cat"** value may/may not exist, but I'm trying to use Python Pandas to check it.

```
for seatbid in patients_df["win_res"]:

    for bid in seatbid["seatbid"]:
```

I tried to access JSON data while writing a loop like that, but it's not being accessed properly.
I simply want to check if **"cat"** exist or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use python's json library as follows:

```
import json
patient_data = json.loads(patientJson)
if "cat" in student:
    print("Key exist in JSON data")
else
    print("Key doesn't exist in JSON data")
```